# Existence of Abelian group extension relative to group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, group-extensions

Let $f: A \to B\ $ be an Abelian group homomorphism. Are there Abelian groups $G,\ H,\  K$ such that $K \subseteq H \subseteq G$ and the map
$$\pi \circ i: H \to G/K$$
which is the composition of projection and inclusion is isomorphic to $f$? By isomorphic to $f\ $I mean there exist isomorphisms $\tau: H \to A\ $ and $\sigma: G/K \to B$ such that $f = \sigma \circ \pi \circ i \circ \tau^{-1}$.

I think it is a quite natural question, since the case where $f$ is epimorphism is a consequence of the fundamental homomorphism theorem. However, I can't prove the existence nor the uniqueness of the group extension. I'm not familiar at all with the general theory of group extension, but maybe the case where $A,\ B\ $are Abelian could be easier.

If such an extension really exists, it would be much more intuitive when dealing with chain complexes and exact sequences, imaging there is a "huge" group such that elements of all other groups are just its cosets.

The question has been answered in MO ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408473/existence-of-abelian-group-extension-relative-to-group-homomorphism/408487#408487)).

Comment: There are certainly counterexamples if you do not assume that the groups are abelian, so I would say that makes the abelian case more difficult!

Comment: Does $K\subset H\subset G$ need to be strict?

Comment: @Bonnaduck No. I have edited the symbols.

Comment: This question has been answered here in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408473/existence-of-abelian-group-extension-relative-to-group-homomorphism/408487#408487

Comment: For reference: next time you crosspost (I think you waited long enough in this case, so that isn't an issue), be sure to indicate in *both* sites that the question is a/has been a crosspost. So your MO question needs to have a note indicating you asked it here (with a link), and the body of this question should have a link to the crossposted MO post. This prevents duplication of efforts.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you. I did give the note when I posted the MO question, but I didn't edit the question here. Sorry if that wasted your time.

Comment: You didn't waste my time; but there was a potential of wasting other people's. What I outlined is standard practice when cross-posting.